# Side menu toggle is not opening

Tags: ionic3

HI i am trying to show side menu for an app, I have a guest user and a registered user. When app loads it lands on login page which will have a guest button on it.
on tapping to it lands on gust home page which has side menus in it, on clicking side menu it opens and closes
The guest page has a login button on tapping it the modal controller opens up and shows the same login page inside that modal on entering user name and password and clicking login button i land on to user home page the side menu there is not opening

but i tried with these following possibilities

```
this.rootPage = 'TabsPage';

this.navCtrl.setRoot("MenuPage");

this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('MenuPage')
```

But with this trials i am not able to open side menu if i navigate from guest home login modal

```
this is common for both home pages
    <ion-header>
        <ion-navbar color="powerred">
            <button ion-button (click)="menuTopg()" start>
                <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-navbar>
     </ion-header>

    menuTopg(){
        this.menuCtrl.open();
    }


in menu.ts 
    if (res.isUserAlreadyLoggedIn) {
                    this.rootPage = 'TabsPage';
}else {
     this.rootPage = 'GuestHomePage';
}
```

Someone please help me

Comment: Try MenuController: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/app/MenuController/

Comment: NO change i am able to click button but menu is not opening

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: any support @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: try This. `<button ion-button menuToggle>  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon</button>` pass `menuToggle` as attribute.